# Can't create a webpage by using github pages

Tags: html, github, github-actions, github-pages, web-hosting

I am not able to create a webpage using github pages can anyone help me out.
I have followed all the instructions given in https://pages.github.com

after creating the repository I went to settings, pages and selected the option deploy from a branch, and selected main and clicked save but the website didnt get created.

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure Github pages is enabled on your repository. The easiest way to do this is to go to the settings tab and click `Pages` in the `Code and automation` section.
(You can also go to https://github.com/adwayithks/adwayithks.github.io/settings/pages but if you have the problem in the future you won't know how to fix it).

From there, you should see a section that looks like this:
[image: build & deployment section]

In the drop-down that says `main`, select `None`. Then, press save. Refresh the page, and go back into that dropdown and select `main` again. Click save, then let GitHub build the website, and it should be online.